# al ingresar un if no me funciona asi lo deje en true - php

Tags: php

tengo una un algoritmo en php donde dependiendo de mi condición envia un mensaje con "$returnData", hasta hi no hay problema pero ahora necesito agregar otra condición en este caso debajo de la consulta select, pero así agregue un true dentro de un if para que siempre entre nunca entra y no se como hacer para que me coja el nuevo if, he intentado agregar el if de varias formas pero no he logrado hacer que entre, no se que me puede estar faltando para poder agregar un if y entre sin ningun problema . Si alguien me puede colaborar se lo agradeceria, muchas gracias.

```js
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

function msg($success,$status,$message,$extra = []){
    return array_merge([
        'success' => $success,
        'status' => $status,
        'message' => $message
    ],$extra);
}

require __DIR__.'/classes/Database.php';
require __DIR__.'/classes/JwtHandler.php';

$db_connection = new Database();
$conn = $db_connection->dbConnection();

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$returnData = [];

// IF REQUEST METHOD IS NOT EQUAL TO POST
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] != "POST"):
    $returnData = msg(0,404,'Page Not Found!');

// CHECKING EMPTY FIELDS
elseif(!isset($data->documento) 
    || !isset($data->clave)
    || empty(trim($data->documento))
    || empty(trim($data->clave))
    ):

    $fields = ['fields' => ['documento','clave']];
    $returnData = msg(0,422,'¡Todos los campos son obligatorios!',$fields);

// IF THERE ARE NO EMPTY FIELDS THEN-
else:
    $documento = trim($data->documento);
    $clave = trim($data->clave);
    

    // CHECKING THE EMAIL FORMAT (IF INVALID FORMAT)
    if(!filter_var($documento)):
        $returnData = msg(0,422,'¡Documento no existe!');
    
    // IF PASSWORD IS LESS THAN 8 THE SHOW THE ERROR
    elseif(strlen($clave) < 8):
        $returnData = msg(0,422,'¡Su contraseña debe tener al menos 8 caracteres!');
        
   

    // THE USER IS ABLE TO PERFORM THE LOGIN ACTION
    else:
        try{
            
            $fetch_user_by_email = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `documento`=:documento and `suspender`= 'habilitado' ";
            $query_stmt = $conn->prepare($fetch_user_by_email);
           // $query_stmt->bindValue(':email', $email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_stmt->bindValue(':documento', $documento,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            // $query_stmt->bindValue(':suspender', $suspender,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_stmt->execute();
            
            
     //aqui necesito agregar esta consulta y se quede en el if pero no paso de largo
            
            if(true){
 
        $returnData = msg(0,422,'¡suspendido!');
            }else{
        $returnData = msg(0,422,'¡ no suspendido!');
            }
        
 // IF THE USER IS FOUNDED BY EMAIL
            if($query_stmt->rowCount()):
                $row = $query_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $check_password = password_verify($clave, $row['clave']);
                
              
                // VERIFYING THE PASSWORD (IS CORRECT OR NOT?)
                // IF PASSWORD IS CORRECT THEN SEND THE LOGIN TOKEN
                if($check_password):

                    $jwt = new JwtHandler();
                    $token = $jwt->_jwt_encode_data(
                        'http://localhost/php_auth_api/',
                        array("user_id"=> $row['id'])
                    );
                    
                    $returnData = [
                        'success' => 1,
                        'message' => 'You have successfully logged in.',
                        'token' => $token
                    ];

                // IF INVALID PASSWORD
                else:
                    $returnData = msg(0,422,'¡Contraseña invalida!');
                endif;
             
            // IF THE USER IS NOT FOUNDED BY EMAIL THEN SHOW THE FOLLOWING ERROR
            else:
                $returnData = msg(0,422,'¡Documento no válido!');
            endif;
                            
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            $returnData = msg(0,500,$e->getMessage());
        }

    endif;

endif;


echo json_encode($returnData);
```

Comment: Sí está entrando al `if`, el problema es que más adelante sobrescribes la variable `$returnData` y es por eso que no se muestra lo que quieres.

Comment: como hago para que me muestre el mensaje del if ya que todos $returnData se muestran

Comment: No se muestran todos, porque en cada asignación creas un arreglo simple. Por favor edita tu pregunta para agregar el código que usas para mostrar lo que haces con `$returnData` al recibirlo en Javascript

Comment: pero si por ejemplo necesito un nuevo arreglo que se ejecute despues de la consulta select, y que se evalue como sería,  es lo que he estado intentando y no lo he logrado.

Comment: Precisamente, por eso es necesario ver lo que haces con la respuesta.

Comment: es simplemente un login, donde el usuario es el campo documento y otro campo es clave, y si el usuario existe me inicia sesión, pero si la contraseña no es valida me muestra el texto del $returnData correspondiente ,  y lo mismo si el documento no  existe y asi con todos los returnData, y lo que necesito es agregar un nuevo $returnData  donde me valide si  el campo suspender del usuario es igual a suspendido me muestre el texto de usuario suspendido.